# Laravel Composer Install Undefined Index Hash

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I tried doing a `composer install` then this is the response:

> Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is
>   recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer
>   self-update" to get the latest version.
>       Loading composer repositories with package information
>       Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>
> [ErrorException]
>      Undefined index: hash
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader]
>   [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ...
>   [packagesN]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: go with  `composer self-update` to ensure your composer is the latest.

Comment: your composer is outdated, you can delete composer.lock and install latest composer, then run composer install

Comment: and yes, delete your `composer.lock` file as stated in this [issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/266).

Answer (score 5):

I think there's something wrong with your composer there's a warning above that says your composer is not updated, try running this command `composer self-update`

Answer (score 2):

try `composer update`
I ever got the problem like this and then, I do `composer update` and it solves my problem